# As of 2015, is there a way to get the boundaries of an italian post code using Google Maps APIs?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I looked at many SO questions referring to a similar topic:

[Google Maps API V3: How to get region border coordinates (polyline) data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194046/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-get-region-border-coordinates-polyline-data)

[Google has started highlighting search areas in Pink color. Is this feature available in Google Maps API 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207045/google-has-started-highlighting-search-areas-in-pink-color-is-this-feature-avai)

[Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result)

[Where do Google and Twitter source political boundaries of cities, regions and states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859307/where-do-google-and-twitter-source-political-boundaries-of-cities-regions-and-s)

And searched for online tools and tools within my country and too:

https://market.mashape.com/vanitysoft/boundaries-io/overview
https://market.mashape.com/vanitysoft/boundaries-io
http://mapit.openpolis.it/postcode/00188.html

But no one of them fits with the task I need to complete (and I tell you why right after explaining the task I have to do):

Basically all I want is, for each Italian *post code* (called *CAP* in Italy) (as of 2015, they are 8709 and I have them all stored in a database's table), find its area coordinates (therefore something like an array with the following structure (it can be a JSON, KML, XML, it doesn't matter as long as the coords are truthful and I can somehow parse them):

```
[
  [ [lat, lng], [lat, lng], [lat, lng], ... ], // Polygon 1
  /*
   * This additional arrays may be here in the case 
   * where a CAP (Italian postal code) is made up of many areas, 
   * therefore each area is a polygon.
   *
   * For example here -> https://www.google.it/maps/place/84020+SA/@40.605482,15.1783416,10.32z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x13396999456508e7:0x1c09e123127ecbc0
   *     
   */ 
  [ [lat, lng], [lat, lng], ... ], // Optional Polygon 2
  ...
  [ [lat, lng], [lat, lng], ... ] // Optional Polygon n
];
```

So that I can draw them with a `google.maps.Polygon` or a custom overlay extending the `google.maps.OverlayView` class on a map. The coordinates of the areas I need are shown by Google here:

https://www.google.it/maps/place/20122+Milano/@45.4628212,9.1931976,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4786c6af4dceb2f5:0x1c0678057ae1afc0

Or here:

https://www.google.it/maps/place/84020+SA/@40.605482,15.1783416,10.32z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x13396999456508e7:0x1c09e123127ecbc0

But I can't find a way to get them in my application and I didn't find such a guide on their site at `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/`. Also, in the SO questions I linked the answers say that Google doesn't provide this data, but, as of 2015, maybe they have changed something?

Now, why no one of the features I have found suits my needs:

- They all address to United States' zip codes only;
- The local Italian site I have found (`mapit.openpolis.it`) doesn't return the coords for the polygon area but just the a single pair of `lat` and `lng` which points to the center of the postal code and also doesn't return anything for some postal codes (CAPs).

What could I do? Is there a way to contact a responsible of the Google Maps API team and ask him what should I do in such a case? (And I am pretty serious so don't laugh at me...).

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: this feature already [has been requested](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109) , you'll have to wait until it will be implemented or find a 3rd-party-solution

Comment: The downvote seems a little bit excessive, I didn't formulate my answer in a wrong way and explained a specific case I need to handle in a pretty clear way and also wrote why what I found (on SO and on other sites/resources) didn't work for me...

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks for the link, I wrote a comment there too. Hope it won't take too long to implement a feature requested 7 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the postal boundaries from open street map.

Comment: Already done. They didn't return boundaries for postal codes in my country (Italy).